# Discord.js Illegal return statement

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I have here a Permission Command for my Discord Bot but it says:"Illegal return statement". On here:

`` return console.log(`Invalid Permissions ${perm}`); ``
and
``` return message.channel.send(`Missing Permissions: \`${invalidPerms}\``); ```.

Full Code:

```
const validPermissions = [
    "CREATE_INSTANT_INVITE",
    "KICK_MEMBERS",
    "BAN_MEMBERS",
    "ADMINISTRATOR",
    "MANAGE_CHANNELS",
    "MANAGE_GUILD",
    "ADD_REACTIONS",
    "VIEW_AUDIT_LOG",
    "PRIORITY_SPEAKER",
    "STREAM",
    "VIEW_CHANNEL",
    "SEND_MESSAGES",
    "SEND_TTS_MESSAGES",
    "MANAGE_MESSAGES",
    "EMBED_LINKS",
    "ATTACH_FILES",
    "READ_MESSAGE_HISTORY",
    "MENTION_EVERYONE",
    "USE_EXTERNAL_EMOJIS",
    "VIEW_GUILD_INSIGHTS",
    "CONNECT",
    "SPEAK",
    "MUTE_MEMBERS",
    "DEAFEN_MEMBERS",
    "MOVE_MEMBERS",
    "USE_VAD",
    "CHANGE_NICKNAME",
    "MANAGE_NICKNAMES",
    "MANAGE_ROLES",
    "MANAGE_WEBHOOKS",
    "MANAGE_EMOJIS",
  ]

  if(command.permissions.length){
    let invalidPerms = []
    for(const perm of command.permissions){
      if(!validPermissions.includes(perm)){
        return console.log(`Invalid Permissions ${perm}`);
      }
      if(!message.member.hasPermission(perm)){
        invalidPerms.push(perm);
      }
    }
    if (invalidPerms.length){
      return message.channel.send(`Missing Permissions: \`${invalidPerms}\``);
    }
  }
```

Hope someone can help :D.

Comment: Is this really the "full code"? Is this code inside a function?

Comment: No its Not in Function and ye thats the full Code

Comment: Is this inside any event?

Comment: No its not just inside the index.js

Comment: It needs to be inside of a function before you can do `return`

Comment: And that's why the error. Put it inside an event or generally a function.

Comment: I added it now in a function and it works THX for help